# Entity Framework relacionamento 1:N

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Olá.

Tenho as seguintes classes...

Classe Vendas:

```
[Table("venda")]
public class Vendas
{        
    public Vendas()
    {
        ItensVendas= new List<ItensVendas>();

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NOME_VENDA { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DATA { get; set; }
    public int ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ItensVendas> ItensVendas{ get; set; }

}
```

Classe ItensVendas:

```
[Table("ITENS_VENDA")]
public class ItensVendas
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ID_RPODUTO { get; set; }
    public int QTD { get; set; }
    public decimal VALOR { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("venda")]
    public int VendaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Vendas venda { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
     public class VendasController : ApiController
        {
            private Contexto ctx = new Contexto();

            [HttpGet]
            public  IEnumerable<Vendas> GetVendas()
            {



                using (Contexto vendaCtx = new Contexto()) {
                    return vendaCtx.Vendas.ToList();

              } 
            }
}
```

Contexto:

```
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public Contexto() : base("conn")
    { 
       this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Vendas> Vendas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItensVendas> ItensVendas { get; set; }
}
```

No método GetVendas do controller, eleme retorna um JSON contendo os dados da venda, mas os itens da venda vem vazio, conforme abaixo.

```
[{"Id":1,"NOME_VENDA":"VENDA 1","DATA":"2017-11-15T20:08:52","ID_CLIENTE":1,"ITENSVENDAS":[]}]
```

Gostaria de trazer os itens desta venda também, como poderia fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer conforme o exemplo abaixo usando o "Include":

```
vendaCtx.Vendas 
  .Include(b => b.ItensVendas).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente a sua configuração está LazyLoading = False;
Se quiser dar uma olhada em como funciona, [clique aqui](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

Em relação a isso, você tem duas opções:

1- Deixa lazy loading = true

2- Dar include no que vc precisa trazer. Exemplo:

```
using (Contexto vendaCtx = new Contexto()) 
{
   return vendaCtx.Vendas.Include(b => b.ItensVendas).ToList();
}
```

nas classes, suas associações no banco devem conter a propriedade `virtual` e usar `ICollection` ao invés de `IEnumerable` (Padrão do lazyloading). Sendo assim, deverá alterar da seguinte maneira sua classe de vendas:

```
[Table("venda")]
public class Vendas
{        
    public Vendas()
    {
        ItensVendas= new List<ItensVendas>();

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NOME_VENDA { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DATA { get; set; }
    public int ID_CLIENTE { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItensVendas> ItensVendas{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Ativei o lazy loading, mas comecei a ter o seguinte erro:
The EntityType Models.Vendas  does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ItensVendas'. E na classe tenho uma property  com este nome.

Comment: Beleza, mas e no seu configuration (onde vc mapeia suas entidades pra gerar o banco), existe esse relacionamento?

Comment: mude para public virtual IEnumerable<ItensVendas> ItensVendas{ get; set; } (coloque o VIRTUAL) e teste de novo, caso esteja mapeado tudo certinho pra gerar o banco.

Comment: Mesmo mudando para public virtual IEnumerable<ItensVendas> ItensVendas{ get; set; }  o erro continua o mesmo.

Comment: Então poste (edite sua pergunta) como vc configurou o mapeamento das suas classes pra eu verificar se tem algum erro?

Comment: @Core alterei para ICollection tb, pois, quando vem do banco, ele entende como uma coleção

Comment: Mesmo erro. Vc falou do mapeamento, teria que ter uma nova classe para isso? Fiz o exemplo de uma video aula , foi feito em cima de uma base já existente.

Comment: você ta mapeando com data annotation?

Comment: Sim. O correto seria utilizar fluent api?

Comment: Eu acredito que seja o melhor cenário. Dificilmente terá problemas desse tipo configurando com o fluent. Se precisar de ajuda com os mapeamentos, pode me procurar.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um sub select para incluir os itens da venda.

```
public  IEnumerable<Vendas> GetVendas()
{
    using (Contexto ctx = new Contexto()) 
    {
        return ctx.Vendas
        .Select(x => new Vendas
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            NOME_VENDA = x.NOME_VENDA,
            DATA = x.DATA,
            ID_CLIENTE = x.ID_CLIENTE,
            ItensVendas = ctx.ItensVendas.Where(i => i.VendaId == x.Id)
        })
        .ToList();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Só lembrando que nesse caso ele fará 2 consultas ao banco e, dependendo da necessidade, poderá ter um desempenho inferior que uma única consulta que traga já o relacionamento (não disse que está errado, só estou comentando de performance)

Comment: @AyrtonGiffoni, não fara duas idas ao banco, pois a query só é finalizada depois do ToList() ...  ou seja até então a query esta sendo montada pelo EF e só com o ToList() ela será lançada ao banco.

Comment: Quando disse duas consultas, quis dizer subquery. No caso, com o join pode ser mais performatico.

Comment: @AyrtonGiffoni, se você analisar a query que o EF montada, vai nota que ele faz isso por traz.